# Eloquent relationship trouble retrieving "belongsTo" relationship

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I'm not entirely sure what the problem is because I don't understand the error message I'm receiving.

I have the following relationships on my Vehicle model

```
/**
 * The dealer the vehicle belongs to (one-to-one relationship)
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function dealer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Dealer');
}

/**
 * The vehicle's specifications
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
 */
public function specifications()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Specification');
}
```

If I call the method below when there's a "province" in the $request I get the following error: Missing argument 2 for App\Project\Frontend\Repo\Vehicle\EloquentVehicle::App\Project\Frontend\Repo\Vehicle{closure}()

I also get the error when there's a "city" in the request.

```
public function vehicleSearchResults($request)
{
    $allowedInput = array(
        'year',
        'make',
        'model',
        'city',
        'province',
        'price',
        'Vehicle Type'
    );

    $query = $this->vehicle;

    foreach($allowedInput as $value)
    {
        if($request->has($value))
        {
            switch ($value)
            {
                case 'year':
                    $query = $query->where('model_year', $request->input($value));
                    break;
                case 'make':
                    $query = $query->where('make', $request->input($value));
                    break;
                case 'model':
                    $query = $query->where('model', $request->input($value));
                    break;
                case 'price':
                    $query = $query->where('price', $request->input($value));
                    break;
                case 'city':
                    $query = $query->whereHas('dealer', function($subQuery, $request, $value)
                    {
                        $subQuery->where('city', $request->input($value))
                            ->where('province', $request->input('province'));
                    })->with('dealer');
                    break;
                case 'province':
                    $query = $query->whereHas('dealer', function($subQuery, $request, $value)
                    {
                        $subQuery->where('province', $request->input($value));
                    })->with('dealer');
                    break;
                case 'Vehicle Type':
                    $query = $query->whereHas('specifications', function($subQuery, $request, $value)
                    {
                        $subQuery->where('spec', $value)
                            ->where('spec_value', $request->input($value));
                    })->with('specifications');
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    return $query->paginate(10);
}
```

I have no idea what the error means, but it points to this code line in the province switch case.

```
$query = $query->whereHas('dealer', function($subQuery, $request, $value)
```

Comment: you are missing the call back in `with('specifications')` must be `with('specifications', function(specifications){  })` also the `with('dealer')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$request` and `$value` variables have the info you need to use in the subquery and the way you was trying to do it was wrong. you were creating new variables instead of using existing ones. The way it should look is like the following:

```
->whereHas('dealer', function($subQuery) use($request)
    {
      $subQuery->where('province', $request->input($value));
    })->with('dealer');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `->with('dealer')` before `->whereHas`

```
$query = $query->with('dealer')
    ->whereHas('dealer', function($subQuery, $request, $value) {
        $subQuery->where('city', $request->input($value))
             ->where('province', $request->input('province'));
    });
```

Comment: This didn't make a difference. I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

your

```
$query = $query->whereHas('dealer', function($subQuery, $request, $value) {
    $subQuery->where('province', $request->input($value));
})->with('dealer');
break;
```

should be like this

```
$search = $request->input($search);
$query = $query->whereHas('dealer', function($subQuery) use ($search) {
{
    $subQuery->where('province', $search);
})->with('dealer');
```

you must `use ($search)` in order to access the variables you wanted in your callback since it is another function

Comment: This made no difference. Still receiving the same error. The api shows that ->with() only accepts one parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = $query->with('dealer')->whereHas('dealer', function($subQuery) use ($request, $value)
{
    $subQuery->where('city', $request->input($value))
        ->where('province', $request->input('province'));
});
```

Only use they $subQuery in your closure and use `use` to inject additional variables